# Creating a "Personal Budget" program in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a Personal budget program (very simple one) with the following instructions:

Implement a personal budget management system. You need to process requests of the following types:

1. date value: Consider that the amount value was earned on the specified date.
2. from to: Calculate the profit within the given date range.

First, you will receive queries with information about earnings, and then you will receive queries to calculate the profit.

**Notes:**

In all date ranges specified as from to, both the from and to dates are inclusive.

1. **Input Format:** In the first line, you'll input the number of days with earnings information, denoted as E. Then, you'll input queries in the formats described above, one per line. Afterward, you'll input the number of profit calculation queries, denoted as Q. Finally, you'll input profit calculation queries, again in the specified formats, one per line.
2. **Output Format:** For each profit calculation query, output an integer on a separate line, representing the profit for the specified date range.

**Constraints:**

1. The number of profit calculation queries, Q, is a natural number not
   exceeding 100,000.
2. All dates are provided in the format YYYY-MM-DD. The dates are valid
   (accounting for leap years) and belong to the interval from 1700 to
   2099.
3. The value in earnings queries is a positive integer not exceeding
   1,000,000.
4. The program should process all queries in 4.9 seconds.

**Hint:** Use std::partial_sum to answer each query, calculating the difference between two partial sums.

**Example:**

**Input:**

- 3
- 2000-01-02 20
- 2000-01-06 10
- 2000-01-03 10
- 2
- 2000-01-01 2000-01-02
- 2000-01-02 2000-01-06

**Output:**

- 20
- 40

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;


std::vector<string> SplitString(std::string& s_date){
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    std::string delim = "-";
    std::vector<string> date_components;
    while ((pos = s_date.find(delim)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s_date.substr(0, pos);
        date_components.push_back(token);
        s_date.erase(0, pos + delim.length());
    }
    date_components.push_back(s_date);
    return date_components;
};


class Date {
public:

    Date(int year, int month, int day) : year_(year), month_(month), day_(day) {};

    static Date from_string(std::string date_string){
        std::vector<string> day_components = SplitString(date_string);

        const int year = std::stoi(day_components[0]);
        const int month = std::stoi(day_components[1]);
        const int day = std::stoi(day_components[2]);

        return {year, month, day};
    }

    int GetYear() const {
        return year_;
    }

    int GetMonth() const {
        return month_;
    }

    int GetDay() const {
        return day_;
    }


private:
    int year_;
    int month_;
    int day_;

};



int jdn (const Date& date){
    //precalculate numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day
    int a = std::floor((14 - date.GetMonth())/12);
    int y = date.GetYear() + 4800 - a;
    int m = date.GetMonth() + 12 * a - 3;

    //calculate JDN:
    int jdn = date.GetDay() + std::floor((153 * m + 2)/5) + 365 * y + std::floor(y/4) - std::floor(y/100) + std::floor(y/400) - 32045;

    return jdn;

}

int day_number_calc (const Date& date, int start_date_jdn){

    //date to calculate jdn
    int date_jdn = jdn(date);

    //calculate JDN according to start and end date
    int day_number = date_jdn - start_date_jdn;

    return day_number;
}


//start date
static const Date start_date = Date::from_string("1700-01-01");
static const int start_date_jdn = jdn(start_date);

//end date
static const Date end_date = Date::from_string("2099-12-31");
static const int end_date_jdn = jdn(end_date);

//difference in days between start date and end date:
static const size_t num_of_days = end_date_jdn - start_date_jdn;


int main() {

    //vector of earnings
    std::vector<int> earnings(num_of_days,0);
 
    size_t Q,E;
    cin >> E;

    //earning in particular day
    for(size_t i = 0; i!= E; ++i){
        
        //variables for user input
        std::string date;
        int sum;

        //user input
        cin >> date >> sum;//read users input

        //transform into date
        const Date date_earning = Date::from_string(date);

        //day number calculation
        int num_date_earning = day_number_calc(date_earning,start_date_jdn);

        //insert into vector
        earnings[num_date_earning] = sum;


    }

    cin >> Q;

    //income calculation
    for(size_t i = 0; i!= Q; ++i){
        
        //variables for user input
        std::string date1;
        std::string date2;

        //user input
        cin >> date1 >> date2; //read users input

        //transform into date
        const Date date_1 = Date::from_string(date1);
        const Date date_2 = Date::from_string(date2);

        //day number calculation
        int num_date_1 = day_number_calc(date_1,start_date_jdn);
        int num_date_2 = day_number_calc(date_2,start_date_jdn);

        //vector<int> temp;
        //std::partial_sum(earnings.begin() + num_date_1, earnings.begin() + num_date_2 + 1,  std::back_inserter(temp));
        //std::cout <<  temp.back() << std::endl;
        std::cout <<  std::accumulate(earnings.begin() + num_date_1, earnings.begin() + num_date_2 + 1, 0) << std::endl;
    }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Code is correct in 4 out of 5 tests, but last one is wrong (no details about the last test were given).

My questions are:

- Where did I make a mistake? I tested it on the heavily, but didn't find anything suspicious
- I don't understand a hint of using std::partial_sum. I thought, that std::accumulate is a perfect candidate for doing the job. Am I wrong?

Comment: What *is* the "last" test? What is its input? What is the actual output? What is the expected output? Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program?

Comment: Hmm, it indeed looks like your code is correct. But the problem is those *online tests* is often the time limit. For each query, you code consistently adds all the values between the start date and the end date, most of which are 0. Maybe you could try to use a map indexed by date. Or better try to find better ways of improving your skills. Remember: those site will not judge the readability, portability, maintainability nor any other best practice rules, and they are a sure way to learn to write code unsuited for production.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reliably reproduce a bug and you are in full control of the code and running environment - that's a nice place to be.
Here is a general tip on debugging. If the result of the last step of your program is not what you expect then check the state of the program before the last step. Does it have all the data records expected there? If you are not sure what std::accumulate does - write your own implementation, it's a simple loop. Break your program into smaller blocks and test each individual block separately. Roll your sleeves up and do the dirty work.